# Can't save dataframe to csv in Python

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to save a dataframe that I have manipulated to calculate mean and median and totals of repeated rows. However, the script seems to run with no problem but without actually outputting the file I request. Can anyone give me any advice as to what is happening?

Here is the code I am using:

```
"""Separate and combine frequencies of like relations, 
then produce extra columns with mean and median of these to
get a better overall picture of each relation"""

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random.mtrand import pareto

def sort_table(fname):
    #read in file
    parent_child_rel = pd.read_csv(fname)
    print(parent_child_rel)

    #drop first column
    parent_child_rel = parent_child_rel.iloc[:,1:]
    print(parent_child_rel)


    #put all upper case
    parent_child_rel = parent_child_rel.apply(lambda x:x.astype(str).str.upper())

    print(parent_child_rel.dtypes) 

    #change datatype to float for nnmbers
    parent_child_rel['Hits'] = parent_child_rel['Hits'].astype('float') 
    parent_child_rel['Score'] = parent_child_rel['Score'].astype('float')

    #group and provide totals and means for hits and score
    aggregated = parent_child_rel.groupby(['parent', 'child'], as_index=False).aggregate({'Hits': np.sum, 'Score': [np.mean, np.median]})


    print(aggregated.dtypes)

    print(aggregated)

    with open('./Sketch_grammar/aggregated_relations_SkG_1.csv', 'a') as outfile:
        aggregated.to_csv(outfile)


def main():
    sort_table('./Sketch_grammar/parent_child_SkG_relations.csv')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main ()
```

Comment: You don't need to use the file handler `open` when using `to_csv` in pandas. It handles that for you. Try using `aggregated.to_csv('./Sketch_grammar/aggregated_relations_skG_1.csv', mode='a')` instead. I'm not clear on why this would be different from what you're doing, but that's the part of the code that looks weird to me, so is worth trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to open the file in order to save it as CSV. Just specify the path to the `to_csv` function.

Also, you have the filename in the `fname` parameter, so you don't need to write it again manually.

Your code would be:

```
"""Separate and combine frequencies of like relations, 
then produce extra columns with mean and median of these to
get a better overall picture of each relation"""

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random.mtrand import pareto

def sort_table(fname):
    #read in file
    parent_child_rel = pd.read_csv(fname)
    print(parent_child_rel)

    #drop first column
    parent_child_rel = parent_child_rel.iloc[:,1:]
    print(parent_child_rel)


    #put all upper case
    parent_child_rel = parent_child_rel.apply(lambda x:x.astype(str).str.upper())

    print(parent_child_rel.dtypes) 

    #change datatype to float for nnmbers
    parent_child_rel['Hits'] = parent_child_rel['Hits'].astype('float') 
    parent_child_rel['Score'] = parent_child_rel['Score'].astype('float')

    #group and provide totals and means for hits and score
    aggregated = parent_child_rel.groupby(['parent', 'child'], as_index=False).aggregate({'Hits': np.sum, 'Score': [np.mean, np.median]})


    print(aggregated.dtypes)

    print(aggregated)

    aggregated.to_csv(fname)


def main():
    sort_table('./Sketch_grammar/parent_child_SkG_relations.csv')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main ()
```

If you don't want to add an extra column with indices (you probably don't) then you should specify it:

```
aggregated.to_csv(fname, index = False)
```

As suggested by @brittenb, you want to append the data to the file, so you should use `mode = "a"`

```
aggregated.to_csv(fname, mode = "a")
```

Comment: Don't forget `mode='a'` since OP wants to append the data per the original code in `open(..., 'a') as outfile`.

Comment: Thank you everyone - that did it!